# Alias template for multiple types

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, type-alias

I have 2 templated types:

```
A<int N>
B<int N>
```

I need these two types to be aliased by a single, third type,

```
C<int N, bool T>
```

Basically what I want is this:

```
template<size_t N, bool T = false>
using C = A<N>;

template<size_t N, bool T = true>
using C = B<N>;
```

However this throws a conflicting declaration error.

error: conflicting declaration of template 'template using C = B' using C = B;

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
template <size_t N, bool T>
using C = std::conditional_t<T, B<N>, A<N>>;
```

Comment: Thanks Brian! That did it for me.

Comment: @throwaway_12348765 don't forget to accept the answer :)